# glMatrix 3.4 from quat to modeView rotation

Tags: webgl, quaternions, gl-matrix

I updated my app in hope to use new func. This is inrterest part of my code:

Part of draw procedure:

```js
// coming from cannonjs
var QP =object.physics.currentBody.quaternion;

var newrot = mat4.create()
mat4.fromQuat(newrot, quat.fromValues(QP.x, QP.y, QP.z, QP.w) )

mat4.multiply(object.mvMatrix, newrot, object.mvMatrix);
```

Rotation is not correct ...
Any suggestion !