From Cannonjs Quat to GLMatrix rotation modelView - fromQuat not working
I use glmatrix 3.4.0 .
Any suggestion !
  mat4.identity(object.mvMatrix);
  this.mvPushMatrix(object.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrixStack);

  mat4.translate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, object.position.worldLocation);


  // case 0: Nor perfect
  // I use local.physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[0] AXIS
  // local.physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1] ANGLE

  // var t = vec3.fromValues(object.rotation.axis.x,object.rotation.axis.z, object.rotation.axis.y);
    // mat4.rotate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, (object.rotation.angle), t);

    // case 1: BAD
    var QP =object.physics.currentBody.quaternion;
    var QUAT = quat.fromValues(QP.x, QP.y, QP.z, QP.w)
    mat4.fromQuat(object.mvMatrix, QUAT)

    // case 3: not perfect
    // mat4.fromRotation(
    //   object.mvMatrix,
    //   (object.rotation.angle),
    //   vec3.create(object.rotation.axis.x, object.rotation.axis.y, object.rotation.axis.z));


Project source

Case 0, 2,


Case 1:




'Not working' is not an actionable problem description. Please specify what you are trying to do and what is happening instead. Given that this is WebGL maybe a screenshot of the rendering would be appropriate.

I agree , ASAP i will post logs...
